# insert timestamp into database, format: 1311602030

Tags: php, database, time

I am woandering how I can store time to my table in this format:

```
1311602030
```

Currently I am doing it this way:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (time) VALUES ( UTC_TIMESTAMP() )
```

which gives me back this:

```
2015-04-14 22:52:11
```

What I could do is:

```
INSERT INTO my_table ( time ) VALUES (  strtotime( UTC_TIMESTAMP() )  )
```

**but isn't there a better way?**

Comment: why is this relevant? sorry, as you realized I'm quite new to programming. The table doesn't really exist for now, I'm just thinking this through. I assumed a standard table with a VARCHAR (60) col.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL, what you are looking for is `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (time) VALUES ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )
```

More information here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Comment: oh nice, didn't know about that. so UNIX gives me the exact same value as my suggestion, right? :)